# All $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $a^2 \leq n$ where $a$ is odd, then $a|n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if we have $a^2 \leq n$ where $a$ is an odd integer, then we also have that $a$ divides $n$.

I tried various methods on this like using $a|n$, $a-2|n$, $a-4|n$, ... but couldn't ultimately succeed. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would expect (but haven't worked it out) that there are in fact very few $n$ (and probably only small $n$) for which this is true.  If you suppose that $7^2\leq n < 9^2=81$ then you would require $3,5,7$ to all divide evenly into $n$, but that would require $n$ to be at least as large as $3\cdot 5\cdot 7=105$, so no $n$ exist in this range.  Similarly, for $9^2\leq n<11^2=121$ you would need $3,5,7,9$ to divide evenly into $n$ meaning $n\geq 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 3 = 315$.  My recommendation is to attempt induction if possible to word conveniently.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,45 all satisfy the conditions.  The question remains if there are any others larger.

Comment: @JMoravitz cannot get too large, the Prime Number Theorem says the product of all (odd) primes up to some $\sqrt n$ is about $e^{\sqrt n},$ much bigger then $n$ unless $n$ is small.

Comment: @WillJagy but if I'm not mistaken, that refers to end behavior.  Are we sure that it doesn't decide to fall far below the expected at some point, far enough to make this possible (or at least to make it harder to tell using the same suggestion)?  Are there strict lower bounds and upper bounds for the product when $n>100$?  Don't need a particularly tight lower bound, just that it is strictly larger than $n$ at all times.

Comment: @JMoravitz, from Rosser and Schoenfeld 1962, (3.16) with Chebyshev's first function says $$   \vartheta (x) > x \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\log x} \right)  $$ for $x \geq 41.$ We would need to subtract $\log 2$ here because we are not saying anything about divisibility by $2.$ We could, in fact, use Chebyshev's second function, but the estimates are less explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is such a number and the odd integer $N$ is defined by the condition $N^2\le n < (N+2)^2$, then $\textrm{lcm}(1,3, \ldots, N)|n$, and in particular $\textrm{lcm}(1,3, \ldots, N) <(N+2)^2$.

Of course, this fails for all large $N$; more precisely, since $N-4, N-2, N$ are (pairwise) relatively prime for odd $N$ and $(N-4)(N-2)N>(N+2)^2$ for $N\ge 7$, it fails for these $N$. Thus we can restrict our search to $n<7^2$, and the complete list of $n$'s with your property is:
$$
1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 30, 45
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mathrm{lcm}(1,3,\ldots,N)\mid n$, rather than $1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot N\mid n$?

Comment: @Batominovski: Yes, thanks, this was incorrect; fixed now.